# How to I export the array in one file to import it into another file in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to export array from one file into another file in react.js. In this array, I randomly select 5 videos from video collection and store these array and export this array to the task1 file and broadcast this url array in the video. See my code.
This is Array.js.

```
function Array (){
    const colUrl =[]
    const url =[
         "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d46Azg3Pm4c",
         "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d46Azg3Pm4c",
         "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d46Azg3Pm4c",
         "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d46Azg3Pm4c",
         "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d46Azg3Pm4c",
         "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d46Azg3Pm4c",
         "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d46Azg3Pm4c",
         "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d46Azg3Pm4c",
         "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d46Azg3Pm4c",
         "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d46Azg3Pm4c",
        ]
     for (var i=0;i<5;i++){
         var rand = url[Math.floor(Math.random()*10)];
         colUrl.push(rand);
      }

      return colUrl;

}

export default Array;
```

This is the file I want to import and use in the video.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player';
import Array from './Array';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

function Task1 () {
    return (
      <div>
          <div className="head">
          <h1>Experiment</h1>
          <h3>Task 1</h3>
          <p>Instruction: This experiment includes 3 tasks. </p>
          <p>In Task 1, you will see 10 videos. </p>
      </div>
     <div className="video">
           <ReactPlayer  url={Array[0]} playing/>
        </div>                  
        <div> 
            <button className="task1-next">Next Video</button>
            <Link to="/task2"><button>Go to Task2</button></Link>

        </div>      

</div>

    )
  }


export default Task1;
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `Array` is a function. What you exported is a function. But what you actually want is an array of 5 random items. So you should execute the function and export the value.

Like this:

```
function Array (){
    const colUrl =[]
    const url =[
         "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d46Azg3Pm4c",
         "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d46Azg3Pm4c",
         "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d46Azg3Pm4c",
         "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d46Azg3Pm4c",
         "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d46Azg3Pm4c",
         "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d46Azg3Pm4c",
         "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d46Azg3Pm4c",
         "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d46Azg3Pm4c",
         "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d46Azg3Pm4c",
         "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d46Azg3Pm4c",
        ]
     for (var i=0;i<5;i++){
         var rand = url[Math.floor(Math.random()*10)];
         colUrl.push(rand);
      }

      return colUrl;

}

export default Array(); // <-- Execute the Array function
```

Comment: @WhiteWhale I'll appreciate if you could mark my answer as correct. :P

Answer (score 0):

You must use the exported function like this.

`<ReactPlayer  url={Array()[0]} playing/>`